# Where to get JSON sample with data that repeats across objects

Tags: json, sorting

Where I can find a JSON sample, preferably an array of objects, in which the data repeats itself? Like an object with that has categories, cities, or information that repeats across other objects.

Something like

```
[
{name: 'jon', age: 33, city: 'Paris', job: 'teacher'},
{name: 'ana', age: 67, city: 'Boston', job: 'retired'},
{name: 'Eva', age: 33, city: 'Shangai', job: 'manager'},
{name: 'Lii', age: 25, city: 'Moscou', job: 'teacher'},
{name: 'Peter', age: 40, city: 'Paris', job: 'developer'},
]
```

As you can see, some information there repeats itself, which enables the sorting of multiple keys. If the information doesn't repeat, I can sort only by one key.

I'm building an data table plugin that enables multiple sorting (sorting multiple columns). To perform the tests, I need a sample (at least 400 objects) that I can sort by multiple columns.

I have some JSON samples, but all values of each key in the objects are different, so I cannot know if my sorting is actually working.

Comment: Why not just create it yourself?

Comment: @HeapOverflow because it takes too much time take to create a large amount of data, which is what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could search for "JSON open data" and will get a list of sites that offer interesting JSON data that should meet your requirement.

- https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?res_format=JSON
- https://data.gov.ie/dataset?res_format=JSON
- https://healthdata.gov/dataset/project-open-data-datajson-file-0
- https://opendata.swiss/en/dataset?res_format=JSON
- etc.